# Error code 1 occuring when connecting to Infobip's SMPP server (to send sms) using PHP

Tags: php, sms, smpp, infobip

I am trying to connect to `Infobip's SMPP` server with the code below but am getting error code 1 `invalid message format`. Please could someone tell me what the problem is. Please could someone also tell me if there is a better code that I can use.
The code am using is on this [link](http://rayed.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/class.smpp.phps)

Comment: lots of syntax errors in that code like  `if($command_lengthsocket, $command_length-4);` & `print "\nsocket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);` & `if ($sizesubmit_sm($source_addr,$destintation_addr,$short_message);`

Comment: Ok thanks. I do appreciate the advise